# How to save echo result into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, s3cmd

I have this output from a `s3cmd ls --list-md5` command.

```
    2013-05-22 12:20   1965154   41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0  s3://company-backup/company/amazon/ip-11-11-111-11/backup_server245/app.20121117040001.gz
    2013-05-22 12:20  11456836   541b1bf78682f48867cc99dbb53c4c3a  s3://company-backup/company/amazon/ip-11-11-111-11/backup_server245/app.20121118040001.gz
    ..
```

I'm trying to verify if the `md5sum` from my object in the bucket match with my `md5sum` in my local machine. So for that I need to get the `hash` result as the `fourth` column and the filename as the `fifth` column.

Like that:

```
41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0  s3://company-backup/company/amazon/ip-11-11-111-11/backup_server245/app.20121117040001.gz
```

But I need only the filename, so for that I'm using the `basename` command (I just don't know how to use it here yet but I will figure out), at the end is looking like this:

```
s3=`s3cmd ls --list-md5 s3://company-backup/company/amazon/ip-11-11-111-11/backup_server245/`;
echo "$s3";

echo "$s3" |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4;
echo "$s3" |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5;
```

Now I need to store the result from the `echo's` at the same variable like these:

```
41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0 app.20121117040001.gz
```

So I could compare the results from `s3cmd ls --list-md5sum` with my `md5sum *.gz` running locally.

**update**
Using the diff approach my command looks like:

```
ls --list-md5 s3://company-backup/company/amazon/ip-11-11-111-11/backup/server245/ \
| tr -s ' ' \
| cut -d ' ' -f 4,5 \
| sed 's= .*/= =' \
| diff -w - <(md5sum /backup/server245/*.gz)
```

Giving the follow result:

```
1,50c1,49
< d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 
< 41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0 app.20121117040001.gz
< 541b1bf78682f48867cc99dbb53c4c3a app.20121118040001.gz
..
---
> 41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0  /backup/diveo245/app.20121117040001.gz
> 541b1bf78682f48867cc99dbb53c4c3a  /backup/diveo245/app.20121118040001.gz
..
```

But how to know the file that is different then ? ('cause all that are equal I can delete alredy)

Comment: can't you just `Var=$(echo....)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need no variables. You can use `diff` to compare the outputs of two different commands:

```
s3cmd ls --list-md5 \
    | tr -s ' ' \
    | cut -d ' ' -f 5,6 \
    | sed 's= .*/= =' \
    | diff -w - <(md5sum *.gz)
```

You might need to `sort` the outputs to have the files in the same order.

Comment: Or omit the `diff` part, write the output to a file like `s3.md5` and use `md5sum -c s3.md5` to check against your local files.

Comment: I just don't understand the output of the diff and how to handle with it. I update my post with the output.

Comment: @ValterHenrique: In your original question, you were running `md5sum *.gz`. If you include path to the `md5sum` arguments, you have to delete it from its output, or `cd /backup/server245/*.gz` and use the command I provided.

Comment: got it, thank you for you help friend! It really help me out.

Answer (score 1):

@choroba's answer is the way to go, but here is another way using variables as requested:

```
s3=`s3cmd ls --list-md5 \
 s3://company-backup/company/amazon/ip-11-11-111-11/backup_server245/ | 
 awk '{print $4,$5}' | awk -F"[/ ]" '{print $1,$NF}'`
echo $s3
 41eae9b40d23de2f02bf07635870f6d0 app.20121117040001.gz
```

Comment: +1 for the `awk -F ... $NF` trick.